# Does Angular Tour of Heroes make use of Angular Routing?

Tags: angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

In the [Tour of Heroes Part 0](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0), it says

> Run the CLI command ng new and provide the name angular-tour-of-heroes, as shown here:
>
> ```
> ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
> ```

However that prompts me for

> Would you like to add Angular routing?

That tutorial doesn't say how to answer this prompt. What should I pick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a "new" thing on Angular CLI, that's why is not on the documentation.

You can say "yes" to the angular routing